# Displaying MySQL database as layer on map?

Tags: software-recommendations, mysql

I have a **mysql database** with lat/long/name and I would like to **show them on the map as a layer** (that is if I update my database you would see the changes when you reload the page or redraw).

Esri ArcGIS javascript automatically retrieves what it needs and displays it. I am familiar with esri js framework but for such a thing I would need an arcgis server which has unlisted costs...

Are there other frameworks or some wrapper that simulates the rest or ArcGIS?

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL as a database and publishing my map on ArcGIS server. I am assuming that you are using ArcMap for publishing your map. just add your table in table of content => right click on table and chose display xy data. analyze your map and register your database directly to ArcGIS server. it will give you a warning on xy data. so mark it as exception. Publish it. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to non-ESRI options, you could create a [GDAL VRT](http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html) file that defines your MySQL layer(s) as a spatial dataset, then you could use any software that can consume the VRT, for example [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) (QGIS), which is a desktop mapping application, or [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/index.html), which can serve tiles for internet mapping applications.

[This example VRT comes directly from MapServer's documentation](http://mapserver.org/input/vector/mysql.html), and you can create it in notepad:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="aqidata">
        <SrcDataSource>MYSQL:aqiTest,user=uuuuu,password=ppppp,host=192.170.1.100,port=3306,tables=testdata</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSQL>SELECT areaID, x, y, sampleValue FROM testdata</SrcSQL>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="x" y="y"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with ESRI js framework you can use

- [MapET Spatial Feature Server](http://mapet.altervista.org/#!sfs-features).

It exposes services compliant to GeoServices REST Specification Version 1.0